# Rename file using regex (Linux Command line)

Tags: debian, rename, regex

I have a backup script which is creating two files:

**a**) db_mywebsite_2018-01-10_00-25.sql.gz

**b**) mywebsite1_2018-01-10_00-01.tar.gz

I'm looking for a Linux command with regex to rename both files to match db_mywebsite.sql.gz mywebsite1.tar.gz

The regex command need to remove date (20XX-XX-XX_XX-XX) from file names (each day it will be different).

Thanks for your help!

Comment: FWIW also at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/416247/rename-file-using-regex-linux-command-line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must have a look at `rename` command. It accepts regex patterns.

Usage:

```
rename [options] [Perl regex search/replace expression] [files]
```

From `man rename`:

```
-v, --verbose
       Verbose: print names of files successfully renamed.
-n, --no-act
       No Action: show what files would have been renamed.
```

**EDIT:**

The appropriate regex for your file names is `_\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}_\d{2}-\d{2}`. So you can find this in file names and then replace it with nothing as below:

```
rename -v -n 's/_\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}_\d{2}-\d{2}//' *.sql.gz
```

I didn't test above command, but it must work.